# Is $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]/ \langle x^2+3,3 \rangle$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Is $R=\mathbb{Z_5}[x]/  \langle x^2+3,3 \rangle$ a field?

*Answer:* If $I=\langle x^2+3,3 \rangle=\{f_1(x)(x^2+3)+f_2(x)3\in\mathbb{Z_5}[x]: f_1(x),f_2(x)\in\mathbb{Z_5}[x]\}$

and if $J=\langle x^2+3 \rangle + \langle 3\rangle=\{g_1(x)+g_2(x): g_1(x)\in\langle x^2+3 \rangle,g_2(x)\in\langle 3\rangle\}=\{a(x)(x^2+3)+b(x)3: a(x),b(x)\in\mathbb{Z_5}[x]\} $.

So can we claim that $I=J$? If this is true then we have that
$$J=\langle gcd(x^2+3,3)\rangle=\langle1\rangle=\mathbb{Z_5}[x]$$

And that means $R\cong \{0_5\}$.

*But I believe that this is wrong. 
Could anybody help me please?*

General Question: In which cases $\langle f(x),g(x) \rangle = \langle f(x) \rangle + \langle g(x) \rangle $?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a typo in the question? Where does it come from. It seems rather unusual.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo and I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: This is yet-another of those examples where writing $\mathbb Z/p$ as $\mathbb Z_p$ makes one wonder whether the $p$-adic integers (invariably denoted $\mathbb Z_p$) weren't intended... perhaps precipitating the questioner's confusion.

Comment: That's not what I meant. The mathematical question just strikes me as a strange one to ask. But, maybe it was the point that it is a strange cornercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you denote by $\;0_5\;$ (the zero element in the field $\;\Bbb F_5\cong\Bbb Z_5\;?$), but observe that

$$1=2\cdot3\in I:=\langle\,x^2+3,\,3\,\rangle\implies I=R=\Bbb F_5[x]\;$$

and thus we indeed get

$$R/I\cong\{0\}\;$$

which is certainly not a field (if we adscribe to widely agreed on condition that a field must have at least two elements)

Comment: $0_5=[0]_{mod5} \in \mathbb{Z_5}$. Your proof is of course more direct than mine. But is mine true? What about the general question?

Comment: @Chris That's always true and, in fact, it is one of the most common definitions of "ideal generated by two elements", which of course can be generalized to any (finite) number of generators. Your proof that $\;I=J\;$ is correct though perhaps unnecessary, and I can't understand how or from where you *then* deduce that $\;I=\langle1\rangle\;$: the gcd is appliable in either case.